# Dymanic add Row in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, salesforce1-app

i have a JSON Object which has Parent Details, In my page i have an option to add New Row dynamically when i click on `+` button.

**`Original JSON`**

```
[
    {
        "canRepeat": true,
        "dynamicName": "Parents / Guardians",
        "dynamicObject": [
            {
                "sectionQuestions": [
                    {                       
                        "question": "Parent First Name",
                        "questionKey": 1,
                        "questionType": "Text",
                        "required": false
                    },
                    {
                        "question": "Parent Last Name",
                        "questionKey": 2,
                        "questionType": "Text",
                        "required": false
                    },
                    {
                        "question": "Parent Email Address",
                        "questionKey": 3,
                        "questionType": "Text",
                        "required": false
                    },
                    {
                        "question": "Parent Phone",
                        "questionKey": 4,
                        "questionType": "Text",
                        "required": false
                    }
                ],
                "wrapperKey": 1
            }
        ],
        "dynamicSectionName": "Parents / Guardians",
        "id": "a0O4W00001Ux8fKUAR",
        "maxRepeatCount": 2,
        "sectionKey": 1,
        "status": true
    }
]
```

Onclick of + button below JS has been called

```
var result = Object.values(this.dynamicSectionData).find(obj => obj.id == event.currentTarget.dataset.sectionid)
            .dynamicObject.find(y => {
                return y['wrapperKey'] == 1
            });

        console.log('result -->' + result);
        let responseJson = JSON.stringify(result);
        console.log("responseJson -->" + responseJson);
```

**Console Log**

```
result -->[object Object]
responseJson -->{"sectionQuestions":[{"question":"Parent First Name","questionKey":1,"questionType":"Text","required":false},{"question":"Parent Last Name","questionKey":2,"questionType":"Text","required":false},{"question":"Parent Email Address","questionKey":3,"questionType":"Email","required":false},{"question":"Parent Phone","questionKey":4,"questionType":"tel","required":false}],"wrapperKey":1}
```

Now I am trying to push that above returned object as below.

```
this.dynamicSectionData[event.currentTarget.dataset.sectionkey].dynamicObject.push({
      result
 })

  let responseJson1 = JSON.stringify(this.dynamicSectionData);
  console.log("responseJson -->" + responseJson1);
```

the above object push print as below

```
[
    {
        "canRepeat": true,
        "dynamicName": "Parents / Guardians",
        "dynamicObject": [
            {
                "sectionQuestions": [
                    {
                        "question": "Parent First Name",
                        "questionKey": 1,
                        "questionType": "Text",
                        "required": false
                    },
                    {
                        "question": "Parent Last Name",
                        "questionKey": 2,
                        "questionType": "Text",
                        "required": false
                    },
                    {
                        "question": "Parent Email Address",
                        "questionKey": 3,
                        "questionType": "Email",
                        "required": false
                    },
                    {
                        "question": "Parent Phone",
                        "questionKey": 4,
                        "questionType": "tel",
                        "required": false
                    }
                ],
                "wrapperKey": 1
            },
            {
                "result": {
                    "sectionQuestions": [
                        {
                            "question": "Parent First Name",
                            "questionKey": 1,
                            "questionType": "Text",
                            "required": false
                        },
                        {
                            "question": "Parent Last Name",
                            "questionKey": 2,
                            "questionType": "Text",
                            "required": false
                        },
                        {
                            "question": "Parent Email Address",
                            "questionKey": 3,
                            "questionType": "Email",
                            "required": false
                        },
                        {
                            "question": "Parent Phone",
                            "questionKey": 4,
                            "questionType": "tel",
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ],
                    "wrapperKey": 1
                }
            }
        ],
        "dynamicScrollSectionName": "#Parents / Guardians",
        "dynamicSectionName": "Parents / Guardians",
        "id": "a0O4W00001Ux8fKUAR",
        "maxRepeatCount": 2,
        "sectionKey": 0,
        "status": true
    } 
]
```

Additional added `"result": {` object in the above request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It did exactly what you asked it to do: you created an object `{...}` with a key of `result`. This is because of the object notation:

```
let helloWorld = 'Hello World';
console.log({helloWorld}); // Outputs {helloWorld: "Hello World"}
```

To fix this, take out the `{}`.

```
this.dynamicSectionData[event.currentTarget.dataset.sectionkey]
  .dynamicObject.push( result )
```